# ASP modalpopupextender and upload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, modalpopupextender

I have a couple upload controls on my page that are being shown by the ajax ModalPopUpExtender, but they don't work at the moment. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong so that they can start getting information into my database?

By the way, I don't know what the hidden field is for or is doing, so if someone understands that, please explain it to me. I didn't write this, I'm just trying to fix it.

```
       <!-- Add a Document -->
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DocumentButton" runat="server">Document</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="DocumentPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="DocumentUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitDocument" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="SubmitDocument_Click" /><asp:Button ID="CancelDocument" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /><asp:HiddenField ID="filename" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>       
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="DocumentModal" runat="server" DropShadow="True" 
            DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" OkControlID="SubmitDocument" PopupControlID="DocumentPanel" TargetControlID="DocumentButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </li>

    Protected Sub SubmitDocument_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitDocument.Click
    'Builds the full absolute URL to be inserted into the database. 
    Dim hostURL As String = Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & Request.Url.Host & ":" & Request.Url.Port & Request.ApplicationPath
    Dim sqlFileHREF As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & " , 4 , '" & LinkTitle.Text & "', '" & hostURL & "uploads/" & ProductID.Value & "/" & filename.Value & "')"
    'Create SQL Connection
    Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=off-db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=*****;database=Products")
    SqlConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlFileHREF, SqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConnection.Close()
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `OkControlID="SubmitDocument"` in the ModalPopupExtender prevent the `Click` event of the `SubmitDocument` Button  to be raised on the server-side.

first thing to try is to remove it and add a `DocumentModal.hide()` in the `SubmitDocument_Click` Sub.

**Update :**
Then you could add a watch to `sqlFileHREF` to find what is causing the `Incorrect syntax near ','.` I suspect that you have a quote or others specials character in it. You could do somthing like `sqlFileHREF.Replace("'", "''")` to double your quotes.

Note : Executing SQL code like this make you vulnerable to SQL Injection!

Note 2 : It would be wise to remove the password from the connection string and replace it with stars in yours future posts (`pwd=********`) (you should edit this one)

**Update 2 :**
Use  `DocumentUpload.FileName` instead of `filename.Value`, it look like the filename HiddenField was there for some unimplemented feature or testing purpose.

Comment: Well that helped, now it looks like the page is refreshing after I click on submit, but it still isn't adding anything to the database and it is not adding a link to the page. It should be adding a new link to the page after upload so that I can tell it worked.

Comment: Oh hey I did that to all of my modals (I have 8) and it worked for the modals with checkboxes inside of them! So now those get updated in the database. So there must be something I am missing with the upload controls. I have never used them before so I'm sure it's some error that I just can't see because of my lack of experience.

Comment: did you try to add a breakpoint in the SubmitDocument_Click sub to see what is happening?

Comment: I just did. I always forget about that. It stops on the sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() and says {"Incorrect syntax near ','."}

Comment: It's gotta be in that INSERT statement, but I have no clue how to change it

Comment: I edited the password - eep! -- I figured it was probably something that is easy to hack since the guy that wrote this graduated under a bad coder....which unfortunately is the same professor I had. :( lol. I will continue working on that insert and let you know. thanks!

Comment: Upon more testing, I have discovered that this query is working correctly, except for this:  & filename.Value &       I guess somehow the filename for the document is just assigned? It must be the hidden field, but it's not working.

Comment: did you try `DocumentUpload.FileName` instead of`filename.Value`

Comment: Hmm, that worked. Not showing up on my page, but it is showing up in the database with the correct filename! On to the next step....Thanks a lot for answering my question!!!!

Comment: More with that insert, there is something wrong with the LinkTitle.Text that is not allowing a title to insert in the database, which is why they are not showing up on the page.

Comment: added a textbox to insert a title with the upload control. fixed.